# Is it possible to add or purchase fonts for Affinity Designer on Windows 7?

Tags: affinity-designer

With Adobe Illustrator it is enough to add a font to the fonts folder, for Affinity Designer I could not found a similar folder.

Comment: The  Fonts folder on Windows PCs is not a font folder only for Adobe products.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Affinity will automatically pick up on installed fonts without having to close the program first. Just install them as you normally would in your OS and Affinity should pick up on them.